# plotting a scatter plot

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```
House_prices = [10050, 42300, 50206, 105000, 22350]
Num_rooms = [4, 5, 6, 10, 12, 2]
```

`code`

```
#This is the code that I have tried:
x = df.House_prices
y = df.Num_rooms
plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.show()
```

I want to plot `"House_prices"` and `"Num_rooms"` into a scatter plot. But I encountered this error `'list' object has no attribute 'House_prices'` 
I don't know whats wrong and I need some help to find out what is wrong. Which part am I wrong? is it the top half: `"x = df.House_prices" and "y = df.Num_rooms"`?

Comment: are `House_prices` and `Num_rooms` list objects. Because `df.House_prices` won't work that way and you could directly pass the list objects instead of caling using df.

Comment: I want to plot both House_prices and Num_rooms into a scatter plot but i do not know how to do it.

Comment: Is there any x axis to the plot? or do you want both of those as scatter points?

Comment: both as scatter points :)

Comment: you could just do `plt.scatter(Num_rooms, House_prices)`. However you need to make sure that the length of both the lists is same. I would remove the last point from the `Num_rooms` list

Comment: Then I will answer accordingly, you could use a log scale to represent that.

Comment: what do you mean by removing the last point from the Num_rooms?

Comment: Ignore that, that was assuming that you wanted to plot the `House_prices` with respect to `Num_rooms`. I have answered now, that should do the job.

Comment: Thank you so much :)

Comment: And yeah you can edit your y limit range however you want, just don't have 0 there as in log scale it goes to infinity. You could also use [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/introduction.html) to get pretty looking plots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, first create a x-axis array or list. I used numpy for that.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(0,len(House_Prices),1)
x1 = np.arange(0, len(Num_rooms),1)

fig=plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
ax.scatter(x,House_Prices)
ax.scatter(x1,Num_rooms)
plt.yscale(value='log')
plt.ylim(0.5,1e5)
plt.show()
```